# How to make a Package with subgroups in Pharo 9

Tags: pharo

In Pharo 9, how do I create a package that has a hierarchy of sub-packages like in "Announcements-Core" where there is an expanding and collapsing arrow?

[image: Pharo 9 package Announcements-Core showing hierarchy]

I thought that it might be based on the names of the packages but when I tried with the following messages to create two classes they just show up as separate packages. What I want is for there to be a package "T-base" that has sub packages "type1" and "type2"?

```
Object subclass: #T1 instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' package: 'T-base-type1'
Object subclass: #T2 instanceVariableNames: '' classVariableNames: '' package: 'T-base-type2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Leandro's answer, to do this in smalltalk code you can do this:

```
t1 := Object subclass: #T1 
             instanceVariableNames: '' 
             classVariableNames: '' 
             package: 'T-base-type1'.

t2 := Object subclass: #T2 
             instanceVariableNames: '' 
             classVariableNames: '' 
             package: 'T-base-type2'.

t1 class package addClassDefinition: t1 toClassTag: #type1.
t2 class package addClassDefinition: t2 toClassTag: #type2.
```

`t1 class package` gives you the `RPackage` instance and you can then add the class to a tag. I also found that you need to have the final part of the package name (eg. type1) be the same as the tag name, otherwise there is an error that the class is "uncategorized".

There is another way as well: You can create the class without the final part of the package name and then send the `category:` message to the class to add it on

```
t1 := Object subclass: #T1 
             instanceVariableNames: '' 
             classVariableNames: '' 
             package: 'T-base'.

t1 category: 'T-base-type1'.
```

Comment: Please go ahead and accept this, your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new package and a (so called) tag inside it use the right-click menu items `New package` and `New tag`. Packages are instances of `RPackage` and tags of `ClyTaggedClassGroup`.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a sentence explaining how the tag affects package hierarchy (which the question was about) would be useful, Leandro? :-)